# Sample Projects with EF6 and MS Identity

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Are there any online sample projects, books or video's that demonstrate the following:

Entity Framework 6, 
Code First,
ASP.NET Identity,
MVC 5,
n-Tiered development,
repository pattern

I'd like to take advantage of the new features, but I'm having trouble understanding how all the new pieces fit together in an n-tiered solution.

Comment: If you come across any let me know! I am very interested in Onion architecture as well (DI, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good question, but unfortunately not a good question for Stack Overflow.

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

I'd suggest you look around for open source projects such as [MVCForum](http://mvcforum.org/) and [EFMVC](http://efmvc.codeplex.com) (they don't yet use MVC5, but find things like them).

MVC5 + EF6 projects will be rather scarce for a while because both technologies are very new.

Answer (score 0):

To echo Rowan, you will be highly unlikely to find books before late Spring next year as ASP.Identity only launched this week/17th October depending on the official launch/RTM date. Jon Galloway has a book [Professional ASP.NET MVC 5](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-MVC-5.productCd-1118794753.html) due for publication with Wrox in March 2014.

PluralSight have a chapter "Identity and Security"  in their [ASP.NET MVC 5 Fundamentals](http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals) training video which may be worth a watch.

Documentation generally seems sparse at the moment.